# Firestore addDoc crashes npm

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I am importing firestore like this

```
import { getFirestore, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
```

but I think it is breaking npm from running my react app because it hangs when trying to compile and then says

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[35196:0x7fb905900000]    69759 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 4063.1 (4140.1) -> 4063.0 (4141.1) MB, 6.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.181, current mu = 0.132) allocation failure 
[35196:0x7fb905900000]    74736 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 4063.5 (4141.1) -> 4063.1 (4141.1) MB, 4957.0 / 0.1 ms  (+ 44.8 ms in 11 steps since start of marking, biggest step 6.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 5015 ms) (average mu = 0.186, current mu = 

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1053472b5 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x105347438 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1054bebb7 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1054beb53 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10565d1d5 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x1056611fb v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x10565dadc v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x10565af8a v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x1056682e0 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x105668361 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x1056352b7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x1059e129e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x105d83299 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
```

NOTE: This does not happen when I remove addDoc but keep getFirebase in the import statement like this:
`import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";`

Comment: Could you try import like `@firebase/firestore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting my node modules folder and then running npm i

Answer (score 0):

If you have seen the error above: **"Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"**, it means your [NodeJS application has ran out of memory](https://medium.com/geekculture/node-js-default-memory-settings-3c0fe8a9ba1), it has consumes more memory than what is allocated and that eventually caused it to kill itself.

To solve this issue you need to increasing the memory limit use command `-- max-old-space-size` .It can be avoid the memory limit issue. You can also try first updating the version of your `nodejs` before running the command below:

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=<size>`

> Just a note, on a machine with 2 GB of memory, consider setting this to 1536 (1.5 GB) to leave some memory for other uses and avoid memory swapping.